# How can I use a variable defined in main in another function? C

Tags: c, cs50

I use `argv[]` to get input from the user. Now I want to use `argv[1]` as intager in another function. So my variable is `int k = atoi(argv[1])` defined in `main`, like you can see it in my code. But I don't know who I can pass this variable to the function called `rotate`. Up to this moment I only found answers using `pointer` which I don't know anything about since I am still new to C and programming. Thanks for your help!

Edit: You can ignore my German comments in the code xD

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
bool only_digits(string digits);
int rotate(string newletter);
    
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int checkfordigits = only_digits(argv[1]);
    
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (checkfordigits == 1)
    {
        printf("Usage ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    
    
    string input = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int encipher = rotate(input);
}
    
bool only_digits(string digits)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = strlen(digits); i < j; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(digits[i]))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (isdigit(digits[i]))
        {
            //Kann das hier leer bleiben
        }
    }
    //weshalb brauche ich hier return?
    return 0;
}
    
    
//Soll aus dem input plaintext den geheimtext machen, um argv[1] im alphabet verschoben
int rotate(string newletter)
{
    int shiftletter = 1;
    for (int i = 0, j = strlen(newletter); i <= j; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(newletter[i]) && isupper(newletter[i]))
        {
            //Erst aus ASCII alphabetical index machen damit buchstaben 0-25 sind statt 65+
            newletter[i] -= 65;
            newletter[i] = ((newletter[i] + shiftletter) % 26);
            newletter[i] += 65;
        }
        else if (isalpha(newletter[i]) && islower(newletter[i]))
        {
            newletter[i] -= 97;
            newletter[i] = ((newletter[i] + shiftletter) % 26);
            newletter[i] += 97;
        }
        else
        {
            newletter[i] += 0;
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", newletter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pass it as a function parameter.

Comment: There are several other places in this code where you pass function parameters. What makes this one different or confusing? The `if (argc != 2)` check should be the first thing in your program before you access `argv[1]`.

Comment: You should check `argc` before you test `only_digits(argv[1])`

Comment: Maybe you didn't realize you can pass more than one parameter to a function? You can. So change it to `int rotate(string newletter, int shiftletter)`

Comment: `string input` is defined in `main()`. `k`' is no different. Pass both to `rotate()`.

Comment: That worked, passing both to rotate(), exactly what I was looking for. Thanks guys

Comment: _Side note:_ Changing `for (int i = 0, j = strlen(digits); i < j; i++)` into `for (int i = 0; digits[i] != 0; i++)` is more efficient.

Comment: _Side note:_ Changing `if (isalpha(newletter[i]) && isupper(newletter[i]))` into `if (isupper(newletter[i]))` is simpler and faster because `isupper` implies `isalpha`

Comment: _Side note:_ Changing `65` into `'A'` and `97` into `'a'` makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you only want to use its value you need to pass it as a parameter

example:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    x += 1;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
}

int main(void)
{
    int y = 5;
    foo(y);
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KrcPh473j

2. If you want to modify it in the function you need to pass pointer to this variable.
   Example:

```
void foo(int *x)
{
    *x += 1;
    printf("x = %d\n", *x);
}

int main(void)
{
    int y = 5;
    foo(&y);
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rEWfzjq98

You can pass as many parameters as you need to the function.
Example:

```
void foo(int x, int y, int z)
{
    printf("sum = %d\n", x * y * z);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    foo(a,b,c);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Kz9drfPq7

Answer (score 0):

You can pass k as a parameter to `rotate` just as how `argc` and `argv` are passed to `main`. You just need to change the function signature of `rotate` to `int rotate(string newletter, int k)`, and then when you call `rotate` you need to do

```
int encipher = rotate(input, k);
```